# Reorder divs based on one class that appears dynamically in one of the divs

Tags: css, css-selectors, flexbox

I have some trouble putting an order for my `div`s in my flex container. 
What is challenging for me is to modify the order of my 7 recipes based on which one has the class "expanded".

When I click on a recipe, it goes from limited size (`250px`) to `100%` wide. And I want to avoid having a line with 2 recipes, 1 line with 1 collapsed recipe and 1 expanded recipe for example:

[image: css-order-issue]

Here is my HTML (`.recipes` is the flex container) with the 7th recipe expanded:

```
<section class="recipes">
  <div class="recipe collapsed" id="recipe1">
  <div class="recipe collapsed" id="recipe2">
  <div class="recipe collapsed" id="recipe3">
  <div class="recipe collapsed" id="recipe4">
  <div class="recipe collapsed" id="recipe5">
  <div class="recipe collapsed" id="recipe6">
  <div class="recipe expanded" id="recipe7">
</section>
```

I tried various selections with orders and it wasn't what I expected. 
The following bring my expanded recipe to the top of the page (don't know exactly why BTW), which is not awful but not perfect either:

```
#recipe1.collapsed { order: 1; }
#recipe2.collapsed { order: 2; }
#recipe3.collapsed { order: 3; }
#recipe4.collapsed { order: 4; }
#recipe5.collapsed { order: 5; }
#recipe6.collapsed { order: 6; }
#recipe7.collapsed { order: 7; }
```

Since my HTML is updated dynamically (only one expanded recipe at a time: if a second one is expanded, the first is collapsed with JS), how can I manage to order the 6 collapsed recipes + the one expanded in the following way?

if `#recipe4` is expanded, I want the following order:

```
#recipe1.collapsed { order: 1; }
#recipe2.collapsed { order: 2; }
#recipe3.collapsed { order: 4; }
#recipe4.expanded { order: 3; }
#recipe5.collapsed { order: 5; }
#recipe6.collapsed { order: 6; }
#recipe7.collapsed { order: 7; }
```

If another recipe is expanded, I want to set another order?

Comment: Try display: flex; with flex orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have rows of 3 elements, then you need to set orders by group of 3, living a gap in between each groups to reorders things line by lines:

example with `tabindex` so div can catch `:focus`

```css
.recipes {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.recipe {
  width:30vw;
  height:50px;
  margin:0.5vw;
  border:solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.recipe:focus {
  width:92vw;
  color:red
}
div:focus:nth-child(2),div:focus:nth-child(3) {
  order:1!important/* important used to overwrite selector with #recipeX mind it while using this for yourself. get rid of !important by increasing selector specifity  */
}
div:focus:nth-child(5),div:focus:nth-child(6) {
  order:6!important/* important used to overwrite selector with #recipeX mind it while using this for yourself. get rid of !important by increasing selector specifity  */
}
/*these divs can have order assigned via nth-child() instead ID (could be created via loop within a script)*/
#recipe1  { order: 3; }
#recipe2  { order: 4; }
#recipe3  { order: 5; }
#recipe4  { order: 9; }
#recipe5  { order: 10; }
#recipe6  { order: 11; }
#recipe7  { order: 15; }

/* demo purpose*/
section {counter-reset:divs}
section div {counter-increment:divs;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;}
section div:before {content:counter(divs)}
```

```html
<section class="recipes">
  <div class="recipe collapsed" id="recipe1" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="recipe collapsed" id="recipe2" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="recipe collapsed" id="recipe3" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="recipe collapsed" id="recipe4" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="recipe collapsed" id="recipe5" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="recipe collapsed" id="recipe6" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="recipe expanded" id="recipe7" tabindex="0"></div>
</section>
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/eEgZyB

Comment: @GCyrilius Why did you use twice "div:focus:nth-child(2),div:focus:nth-child(3) {
  order:1!important}" please?

Comment: @Genia , oh , just noticed your message and that extra/doubled piece of code . a mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a simple JavaScript code:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".recipe"); // get all recipes
items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.onclick = function() { // add onClick event
        var item_index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(items, item); // find the index of the item which is clicked

        // Add 1 to (index+1) until it reaches the clicked item
        var plus = 1;
        items.forEach(function(item,index) {
            if (index == item_index)
                plus = 0;
            item.style.order = index+1+plus;
        });

        // set the order of clicked item to 1
        this.style.order = 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: In this code I set the order of clicked item to 1. you can easily change it to 3

Comment: Unfortunately, as my flex box makes rows of 3, 2 and 1 recipes, your code doesn't allow me to dynamically set a different order on the divs.